# Can anybody explain this for me, please?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"Earlier this year, Sam Stovall, U.S. equity strategist at S&P Global Market Intelligence, noted that the S&P 500  has a fairly good record of predicting election results.
Since 1944, the incumbent person or party was reelected **82% of the time** when the S&P 500 rose between July 31 and Oct. 31, according to Stovall. The only exceptions were in 1968 and 1980, when there were popular third-party candidates in the picture."

source: http://www.marketwatch.com/story/the-stock-market-has-already-picked-the-next-us-president-2016-08-29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'd need to know the number of times the S&P 500 rose between those dates to confirm the number, but the phrase *82% of the time* means **the number of times** the incumbent was re-elected *divided by* t**he number of times** the S&P 500 rose between those dates.  When we make the generalizing statement, we use the singular, "of the time", consolidating the times into a whole and taking some fraction of it:

> I go to this restaurant most of the time.

I go to several restaurants. This is the one I go to *most often*.

> She took the train home 100 times last year.  It was late leaving the
>   station 25 times. It was late *25 percent* **of the time**.

"25 percent" expresses the relevant fraction of the whole.